# reason for using three open-close quotes when using re.verbose in python

Tags: python

I'm just curious as to why most examples I've seen that make use of re.verbose when using regular expressions, use '''?

An example I found is shown below

```
address = re.compile(
    '''              #THIS
    [\w\d.+-]+       # username
    @
    ([\w\d.]+\.)+    # domain name prefix
    (com|org|edu)    # we should support more top-level domains
    ''',             #AND  THIS  
    re.UNICODE | re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Note that in general you want to use "raw" strings by starting them with e.g. `r'''`.  This will allow you to use regexp escape sequences (e.g. `\w`) in the regex without worrying about them being interpreted as string escapes like `\n`.  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `'''` allows the string to span multiple lines, so they can break down each part of the re instead of having one long line.

It is done for code readability, not functionality.

See the [Python Tutorial strings section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for more information about strings that span multiple lines.

Comment: This is definitely the number one reason.  Triple-quoting also allows the use of unescaped single quotes in the regexp.